# How can I let AdMob approve my app if test ads are not allowed for the app store submission?

Tags: flutter, google-play, admob, app-store

I have almost completed programming my flutter app but now I wonder how I can make my app show real Admob Ads for the app that gets reviewed by Apple/Google (as test-ads are not allowed) if AdMob doesn't allow showing real ads if the app is not already listed on an app store? How can AdMob review whether my app is suitable if I can't even get listed on the app stores since my app can't show real ads.

AdMob Documentation

> In order for your app to be reviewed:
>
> Your app must be published. This means that your app is available to
> users.  Your app must be listed in a supported store. This means that
> your app has a store listing and is available for download from that
> app store.  Your app must be set up correctly in AdMob and linked to a
> supported store.

Apple Documentation

> 2.5.10 Apps should not be submitted with empty ad banners or test advertisements.